# ¿Cómo controlar procesos de windows en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que sirve para administrar y controlar procesos de windows desde una plataforma asp.net y c#. Necesito visualizar las aplicaciones que están corriendo en el servidor donde se ejecuta la aplicación, por ejemplo: notepad, cmd, chrome, etc. y tener la capacidad de cerrar o reiniciar dichos procesos. ¿Cómo se puede acceder a la información de los procesos programáticamente utilizando C#?

Answer (score 2):

Los procesos que estan ejecutando se pueden obtener mediente la clase

[Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usando el metodo [GetProcesses()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx) obtendrias la lista que esta ejecutando.

```
Process[] localProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Para cerrar un proceso se usa el [Kill()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx)

Pero son procesos **no se reinician una vez que los terminas** deberas ejecutarlo nuevamente.

Los servicios de windows son los que pueden reiniarse, pero para controlarlos es una clase diferente

[ServiceController (Clase)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

los servicio que ejecutan en la pc si pueden iniciarse, detenerse o reiniciar.